# Book where alien ships use a wall of fire to destroy us. cover art shows a manned 155mm howitzer pointed at their ship

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a hardcopy sci fi book from 20 years ago. All I can recall is that the aliens have huge craft that use shielding rendering our attack from missiles & canon useless. They drag an impermeable wall of fire behind them to destroy whichever ground target they fancy. The part of the plot I cannot recall is how they interacted with us.

The only thing I clearly remember is the cover art:
a colored drawing of a soldier sitting at the computer controller for a 155mm howitzer which was pointed at one of their craft and a huge sheet of fire following it.